# Why my constraint validation works when declared on the form builder but got ignored when configured on my entity?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a `ProjetContact` entity that have a `roles` relation.  A ProjetContact entity must have at least one role.  So I added a Count constraint as annotation.

```
/**
 * @var Collection
 * 
 * @Assert\Count(min=1, minMessage="Vous devez sélectionner au moins un rôle par contact")
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ContactRole")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *   name="projet_contact_role",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="projet_contact_role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * ) 
 */
 private $roles;
```

But, this doesn't work, the constraint is ignored.  A user can submit a form without selecting any role.

I found that if I configure the validator on the form builder, it works.

```
$builder
  ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Rôles',
    'class' => 'MyIntranetBundle:ContactRole',
    [...]
    'constraints' => new Count(
      array('min'=>1, 'minMessage'=>'Vous devez sélectionner au moins un rôle par contact')
    )
  ))
->[...]
```

I would prefer configuring my validator directly on my entity.  Why this doesn't work that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `@Assert\Valid()` on the parent entity that use `ProjetContact`.

```
/**
* @var Collection
* 
* @Assert\Valid()
* 
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjetContact", mappedBy="projet", cascade={"persist","remove"})
*/
private $contacts;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible causes:

1. You didn't import `Assert` correctly in your entity definition (should be `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;`)
2. You have validation groups defined for the form, and didn't include `Default` group.

Comment: I didn't included the import section in my post, but Assert is already imported.  I don't have any validation groups.